# Continously check external storage to video stop recording

Tags: android, local-storage, android-sdcard, mediarecorder

I am working on a video camera app which will record a video but i want to stop the video recording when the user runs out of memory ,for that I will have to continuously check the size of video and sd card

The scenario is when I am recording the file size will change continuously so how do I stop recording video inside activity and how do i continuously check sdcard size

code to check sd card size is

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());        
            long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
            long totalSize = statFs.getBlockCount()*blockSize;
            long availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks()*blockSize;
            long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks()*blockSize;

            long megAvailablenew = availableSize/ (1024 * 1024);
            Log.e("","Available MB : "+megAvailablenew+" avail "+availableSize)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer this-

```
public long TotalMemory()//Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
    {
        StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());   
        long Total = ( (long) statFs.getBlockCount() *  (long) statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
        return Total;
    }

public long FreeMemory()
{
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    long Free  = (statFs.getAvailableBlocks() *  (long) statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
    return Free;
}

public long BusyMemory()
{
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());   
    long Total = ( (long) statFs.getBlockCount() * (long) statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
    long Free  = (statFs.getAvailableBlocks() *  (long) statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
    long Busy  = Total - Free;
    return Busy;
}
```

Comment: You can set broadcast while recording check the status in receiver

Comment: pls go through my question i have asked to stop recording when it has reached the memory limit

Comment: whats the broadcast to check the memory status

Comment: Or you can also check it in service of recording.and if recorded files size is nearer to free memory size you can stop your recording

Comment: How do i get media recorder file size